# Resize photo in Appcelerator Titanium before save

Tags: android, iphone, camera, titanium, appcelerator

I'm having a little trouble in saving a photo with Appcelerator.

I'm taking a photo and saving it, okay, thats work and here is the code:

```
var cameraOverlay = Ti.UI.createView({
    width:'100%',
    height:'100%'
});

var porcoOverlay = Ti.UI.createView({
    width: '90%',
    height: '100%',
    left: 0,
    top: 0
});
var porco = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    width: 200,
    height: 238,
    top: 10,
    left: 10,
    image:'images/pig.png',
    touchEnabled: false
});
porcoOverlay.add(porco);
cameraOverlay.add(porcoOverlay);

var menuOverlay = Ti.UI.createView({
    width: '10%',
    height: '100%',
    right: 0,
    top: 0
});
var takeFoto = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title: 'PH',
    bottom: 10,
    right: 10
});
menuOverlay.add(takeFoto);
cameraOverlay.add(menuOverlay);



Ti.Media.showCamera({
    showControls:true,
    overlay: cameraOverlay,
    saveToPhotoGallery: true,
    success:function(event) {

        var cropRect = event.cropRect;
        var image = event.media;

        var f = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,'camera_photo.png');
        f.write(image);

    }
});

takeFoto.addEventListener('click',function(){
    Ti.Media.takePicture();
});
```

And here are my problem:

1 - The autofocus doesn't work;

2 - The image resolution is always: 320*240;

3 - I want to join overlay with the photo and save;

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

@Bruno Almeida 
Your Code is almost Right. 
According this Query you want to save image with your Predefine Height and Width (Pixels).
If Yes, then you Can try this Example [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519293/resize-photo-in-appcelerator-titanium-before-save) one is very use for me I think alos your. 
for Help ! understand This code

```
var ImageFactory = require('ti.imagefactory');
// Save your Image 

savedFile.write(event.media);
// Read you Image in Blob Format                    
var blob = savedFile.read();

//  Resize this image through use ImageFactory Module.

newBlob = ImageFactory.imageAsResized(blob, { width:300, height:300, quality:ImageFactory.QUALITY_LOW });
  savedFile.write(newBlob);
  blob = savedFile.read();
```

Comment: Thank You! But I tried to put this code in the success callback, insert the module in the correct folder, but didn't take effect. The image is still with 320*240, but I want to use my 5mp camera to take a HIGH QUALITY photo. I never worked with images before, so I'm really lost!

Comment: It's the galaxy nexus, have 5MP camera! But with the overlay, the photo is always 320*240, if I took off the overlay, the camera takes normal photos in 5mp and with autofocus.

Answer (score -1):

```
MV.utils.ImageUtils.resize(image, 500, 500);
```

Comment: Brevity is accepted but a little explanation is always more helpful :)